# Нет перевода строк в окне настроек в пункте про данные о действиях

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, настройки-профиля, приватность

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Строка:

> Disabled

И ещё:

> There is nothing to download because you are opted out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://ru.traducir.win/string/10764

Предложил:

> Отключено

https://ru.traducir.win/string/10212

Предложил:

> Нет данных для загрузки, т.к. настройка отключена.

Comment: Немного изменил и утвердил.